# Objectivc-c - Making objects of values in pList

Tags: objective-c, plist

I have a pList looking like this when i log it:

```
    {
    Hans =         {
        Highscore = 0;
        Name = Hans;
    };
},
    {
    joe =         {
        Highscore = 0;
        Name = joe;
    };
},
    {
    Iben =         {
        Highscore = 0;
        Name = Iben;
    };
},
    {
    Erik =         {
        Highscore = 0;
        Name = Erik;
    };
}
```

I would really like to make these values in my pList into objects of Players when ViewDidLoad is called. Im not sure how to do so thought. Can somebody maybe help?

Comment: Are you looking to generate a class in runtime according to what you plist says or you already have 'Player' class and want to create instances of 'Player' using this plist?

Comment: I would like to make a player object for each name and highscore and put them into a MutableArray to then put into my UITableview. I already have the Player class with the two properties name and highscore. So the Player i make just need to have name and highscore matching what is in the pList

Answer (score 0):

Load the plist into an array (appears you already have this but still I added this step)

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PlayerData" //Filename
                                                 ofType:@"plist"];

NSArray *loadedArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Create an empty mutable array to store your player instances:

```
NSMutableArray *playersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Loop through your loaded array, creating `Player` instances and adding them to your mutable array

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in loadedArray) {
    Player *player = [[Player alloc] init];
    player.name = dictionary[@"Name"];
    player.highscore = dictionary[@"Highscore"];
    [playersArray addObject:player];
}
```

Note: Ideally you want a initialiser method in your player, like this:

```
- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name highscore:(NSNumber *)highscore;
```

Comment: Or a convenience initializer like `+(instancetype)fromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict`

Comment: I have made the pList like this: 
finalPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pListPlayer.plist"];

does that mean i should write it like this:

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:finalPath 
                                                 ofType:@"plist"];

Comment: Not really, it is up to you how you load the plist into an array, you can ignore the first part of the answer if you already have the array.